# jQuery Autocomplete doesn't work (JSON PHP to js)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have to make AutoComplete with Countries from SQL.

**1. php** 
$sql_list_countries=(SQL request)

**var_dump**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'meta_value' => string 'United States' (length=13)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'meta_value' => string 'Germany' (length=7)
```

2. **script javascript (at php file):**

var country_array = ;

var test = JSON.stringify (country_array);

console.log (test);

```
 [{"meta_value":"United States"},{"meta_value":"Germany"}]
```

**3. js file (!)**

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

console.log (ff);

jQuery( '#city_form' ).autocomplete({

source: ff

});

```
 [{"meta_value":"United States"},{"meta_value":"Germany"}]
```

**So as you see js recieve value of ff as array but Autocomplete function doesn't work.** Although if I change ff in js with array var ff = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp"] it works.

Comment: I expect auto complete relies on the data being in alphabetical order, your `var_dump` shows the PHP array isn't sorted - try sorting it before post.

Comment: as @litechip have pointed, your data is wrong, you should read the doc more carefully. It accepts object in a format `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

Comment: and you pass `["label": "value"]` which is wrong

Comment: @Rudu I have sorted it array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'meta_value' => string 'Germany' (length=7)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'meta_value' => string 'United States' (length=13)
 But it doesn't help.

Comment: @user907860 It not request but respond from server.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify source as

- An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
- An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

look [jquery docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)